# Creating new Database in Oracle 10g XE

Tags: database, oracle

**Problem with creating new Database in Oracle Express Edition.**

Platform: Ubuntu 12
Oracle : 10g Express edition

I am trying to create a new database in oracle and I took the help of [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10739/create.htm#i1017640) to achieve that.

I was successful in creating the 'Initialization Parameter File' for Database 'mynewdb'. Even, I have changed the environment variable `ORACLE_SID` to point to value 'mynewdb'.

The problem is, when I try to connect to database by hitting `CONNECT SYS/passwd AS SYSDBA` , it prompted an error saying Insufficient Privileges'. So, I restored the ORACLE_SID variable back to 'XE'.

Now, I logged in with SYSDBA privileges and then I issued 'CREATE DATABASE' command to create the 'mynewdb' database. This time it prompted again an error saying

> database name 'MYNEWDB' does not match parameter db_name 'XE'

Comment: see other anwsers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534136/how-to-create-a-database-after-installing-oracle-database-11g-express-edition

Comment: In 90% of the cases where people claim they need a new "database" in Oracle, they just need a new schema/user. And I don't think XE supports more than one instance any (which is a "database" in Oracle).

Comment: Your comment should probably be posted as answer. There are 2 parts in it. 1- There is no way to create a new database in Oracle 10g XE; 2- It is not necessary. One should create a new user, grant the appropriate permissions and connect as this new user.