# Creating a new database and new connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, database-connection, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've installed SQL Developer on my system. No connections are being shown in my system yet. How do I create a new connection. Must I create a database first? If yes, then how do I create a new database. The SQL Query Editor window is not opening because there is no connection. All of this because there is no database. How do I create an empty database and then connect to it.

Comment: Did you install Oracle database first?

Comment: No. How to do it. I didn't get it from the documentation.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This tutorial should help you:

[Getting Started with Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm)

See the prerequisites:

1. Install Oracle SQL Developer. ***You already have it.***
2. Install the Oracle Database. Download available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html).
3. Unlock the HR user. Login to SQL*Plus as the **SYS** user and execute the following command:

   `alter user hr identified by hr account unlock;`
4. Download and unzip the **sqldev_mngdb.zip** file that contains all the files you need to perform this tutorial.

---

Another version from May 2011: [Getting Started with Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/getting-started-155046.html)

---

For more info check this related question:

[How to create a new database after initally installing oracle database 11g Express Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9534136/114029)

Comment: @SachinKainth - Installing MySQL is such a relief!

Comment: 'alter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 6):

1. Connect to sys.
2. Give your password for sys.
3. Unlock hr user by running following query:

   `alter user hr identified by hr account unlock;`
4. Then, Click on new connection
5. Give connection name as HR_ORCL

   `Username: hr`

   `Password: hr`

   `Connection Type: Basic`

   `Role: default`

   `Hostname: localhost`

   `Port: 1521`

   `SID: xe`
6. Click on test and Connect

Comment: Please don't provide duplicate answer.

Comment: Username and password are upper case HR

Answer (score 1):

Open Oracle SQLDeveloper

Right click on connection tab and select new connection

Enter HR_ORCL in connection name and HR for the username and password.

Specify localhost for your Hostname and enter ORCL for the SID.

Click Test.

The status of the connection Test Successfully.

The connection was not saved however click on Save button to save the connection. And then click on Connect button to connect your database.

The connection is saved and you see the connection list.

Comment: Copy-pasting from the documentation is not an answer.