# How can I make local connection in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have downloaded the SQL Developer. Currently, I am using my school database but it is for temporary use. I want to use it after finishing my college. I do not know how can I make local connection in SQL Developer. Can you please help me in this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a new database and new connection in Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680321/creating-a-new-database-and-new-connection-in-oracle-sql-developer)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL Developer is a tool you use to access an Oracle database.

So, if you want to use Oracle on your own computer, regardless there is (or is not) a connection to your school network, you'll have to install the database as well. I'd suggest Oracle 11g Express Edition. The installation process is simple; more or less, clicking NEXT a few times does the job. I'd, though, recommend you to follow the Installation Guide and pay attention to what the Installer asks (for example, write down passwords you choose).

Furthermore, in order to "copy" the database (actually, I believe you mean "schema" in this case) to your database, the right way to do that is to use Data Pump. You'd use Export in school to export the database, and Import on your computer to import it.

However, as Data Pump requires access to a *directory* (it is an Oracle object which points to a file system directory, usually on the database server; it is created by SYS and other users are granted read and/or write privileges on it). If you can't get access to it, you can use the *original* EXP and IMP utilities. EXP creates the DMP file *locally*; you'd put it onto a memory stick (or, if you're on the network, copy it directly to your PC) and import it.

If you're unsure of whether you can (or can not) do that, ask your teacher.

Once the schema is imported into your database, use SQL Developer to access it. Should be no problem to do that.