# Understanding connections in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried looking at a few resources but still remain a bit confused. Hopefully someone can explain to me exactly what is going on.

I installed oracle 19c. I then set up several connections. My main question is: what is a connection? Is a connection a database? What is being connected to. Other resources state that 19c is itself a database, but what if I want a second one?

I got some help from this link but still have more questions.
[Creating a new database and new connection in Oracle SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680321/creating-a-new-database-and-new-connection-in-oracle-sql-developer)

[image]

Comment: Please, check this: [Oracle Concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/introduction-to-oracle-database.html#GUID-CF765A7D-9429-4901-BF33-36E0B0220293). Oracle Database is software that can manage databases, which are just files. To allow you to operate with that files you need to run an **instance**, which is a memory structures and processes to operate with DB files. So connection is a communication channel between your software and database instance. One instance can have multiple connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, when you connect, you connect as user. This user has its own workspace called "schema". Hence, user = schema. What you see in Sql Developer is your connection as specific user and all the objects under this user's schema. So, connection there is just a saved set of connection parameters, such as server, schema, user, password, type of connection, etc

Database is a bunch of files where your data is stored. Then at runtime, instance of that database is created in memory - this is what you connect to. You can't connect to the database, although, commonly people do say *"connected to the oracle database"*. If you connect as `system` user, you can have access to many schemas. You, as user or schema, can be given permissions to access other schemas as well

> *"When creating the connections, the only thing that I ever entered differently was the name/username/and password section."*

Out of `name/username/password` - on the picture I see only name (connection name), which is arbitrary, and is not part of database. `username` is part of database. And if your `username` is different in each connection, you're connected to different schemas.

Comment: Ok, but a schema is not a database correct? All these users are connected to 1 database?

Comment: No. Database is a bunch of files where your data is stored. Then at runtime, instance of that database is created in memory - this is what you connect to. You can't connect to the database, although , commonly people do say *"connected to the oracle database"*. If you connect as `system` user, you can have access to many schemas. You, as user or schema, can be given permissions to access other schemas as well

Comment: @The_Redhawk *"but a schema is not a database correct?"* - correct, schema is part of database.. *"All these users are connected to 1 database"* - can be one database or many different databases

Comment: Assuming All I did was install oracle 19c and create the users/schemas in the picture above, I should only have 1 database then?

Comment: @The_Redhawk Have you installed Oracle Database or the Oracle Sql Developer? If you installed the entire database - yes, you have one database. **you're assuming** that your picture gives any sort of description of what you **really** have. But this is not true. All I see is 4 connections - "hr", "rthomas", "system" + 1. These are only some arbitrary names of the saved connections. Inside them, if I want, they can be pointed to the same instance and same schema, or to 4 different instances, or to same instance but different schemas.

Comment: I have oracle database installed. When creating the connections, the only thing that I ever entered differently was the name/username/and password section. Everything else, like service name I kept consistent. Each connection has different tables in it. I am guessing then that I have 4 different schemas on the same instance. Thanks for the help btw, it is appreciated.

Comment: @The_Redhawk if you connected 4 times to same SID then all your connections are connected to the same instance. Out of  `name/username/password` - on the picture I see only `name`, which is arbitrary, and is not part of database. `username` is part of database. And if your `username` is different in each connection, you're connected to different schemas. Because remember - user=schema. `CREATE USER john IDENTIFIED BY x` - creates schema

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. So essentially right now I have 1 database and 1 instance of that database with 4 schemas, each identified by a different name.