# How to creating new database instance in redhat linux

Tags: linux, oracle

I installed oracle 11g rpm package from oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm.zip  in redhat linux.By default i get database XE .My question is how can i create new database like XE i mean new instance.Please can any one suggest me how to do and please suggest me any blogs for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a database after installing oracle database 11g Express Edition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534136/how-to-create-a-database-after-installing-oracle-database-11g-express-edition)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what OS you use, you can run [DBCA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSQhnOP6FCs) (Database Configuration Assistant) it is easy to create a database using this tool. Also pay attention to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534136/how-to-create-a-database-after-installing-oracle-database-11g-express-edition)