# what is purpose of giving user name and password during the oracle 11g expression edition?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed oracle 11g XE on my system.During the installation I have given a password. Is that a database password or the password for the system schema? How do i create different database in oracle 11g XE?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW124

Comment: Also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534136/how-to-create-a-new-database-after-initally-installing-oracle-database-11g-expre?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

it is about `dba` password

n the Specify Database Passwords window, enter and confirm the password to use for the `SYS` and `SYSTEM` database accounts